# ASP.Net Core EF M-M Instance Cannot be Tracked

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

Consider the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'OrderRegion' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '[Orderid: 10, RegionId: 1]' is already being tracked...
```

Also, consider the following classes (slightly snipped for brevity):

```
public class Order
…
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
…
[Display(Name = "Regions")]
public ICollection<OrderRegion> OrderRegions { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Stores")]
public ICollection<OrderStore> OrderStores { get; set; }

public class OrderRegion
{
    //[Key]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    //[Key]
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public Region Region { get; set; }
}

    public class OrderStore
{
    //[Key]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    //[Key]
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    public Store Store { get; set; }
}
```

Also of relevance is the Context where I create the relationships:

```
public class MyContext:DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<AzureOrdersContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Order> Order { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderRegion> OrderRegion { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderStore> OrderStore { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        …
        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderRegion>()
            .HasKey(nr => new { nr.OrderId, nr.RegionId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderRegion>()
            .HasOne(nr => nr.Order)
            .WithMany(n => n.OrderRegions)
            .HasForeignKey(nr => nr.OrderId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderRegion>()
            .HasOne(nr => nr.Region)
            .WithMany(n => n.OrderRegions)
            .HasForeignKey(nr => nr.RegionId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderStore>()
          .HasKey(nr => new { nr.OrderId, nr.StoreId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderStore>()
            .HasOne(nr => nr.Order)
            .WithMany(n => n.OrderStores)
            .HasForeignKey(nr => nr.OrderId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderStore>()
            .HasOne(nr => nr.Store)
            .WithMany(n => n.OrderStores)
            .HasForeignKey(nr => nr.StoreId);
    }
}
```

And finally, my "Edit.cshtml.cs" where my error is thrown (snipped a lot):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int? id, int[] AssignedRegions, int[] AssignedStores)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        var Ordertoupdate = await _context.Order
        .Include(i => i.OrderRegions).ThenInclude(navigationPropertyPath: i => i.Region)
        .Include(i => i.OrderStores).ThenInclude(navigationPropertyPath: i => i.Store)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

       ...

        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Web.Models.Order>(
                        Ordertoupdate,
                        "Order",
                        i => i.CreatedOn, 
                        i => i.CreatedBy, 
                        i => i.ModifiedBy, i => i.ExpirationDate,
                        ...))
        {
            UpdateOrderRegions(_context, AssignedRegions, Ordertoupdate);
            UpdateOrderStores(_context, AssignedStores, Ordertoupdate);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
        UpdateOrderRegions(_context, AssignedRegions, Ordertoupdate);
        UpdateOrderStores(_context, AssignedStores, Ordertoupdate);
        PopulateAssignedRegions(_context, Ordertoupdate);
        PopulateAssignedStores(_context, Ordertoupdate);
        return Page();
    }
```

The error is getting thrown on _context.SaveChangesAsync(); Any ideas? I'm certain I'm just doing something stupid and not seeing a simple fix.

Updating to include UpdateOrderRegions as requested:

```
public void UpdateOrderRegions (AzureOrdersContext _context, int[] SelectedRegions, Web.Models.Order OrderToUpdate)
    {
        if (SelectedRegions == null)
        {
            OrderToUpdate.OrderRegions = new List<OrderRegion>();
            return;
        }
        var StoreRegionsToDelete= OrderToUpdate.OrderRegions.Where<OrderRegion>(nr => {
            return !SelectedRegions.AsQueryable<Int32>().Contains<Int32>(nr.RegionId);
        });

        StoreRegionsToDelete.ToList().ForEach(r => { OrderToUpdate.OrderRegions.Remove(r); });

        var StoreRegionsToAdd = SelectedRegions.AsQueryable<Int32>().Where<Int32>(regionId => 
            !OrderToUpdate.OrderRegions.Any( nr=> nr.RegionId == regionId) 
        );
        StoreRegionsToAdd.ToList().ForEach(regionId => 
        OrderToUpdate.OrderRegions.Add(new OrderRegion
        {
            OrderId = OrderToUpdate.Id,
            RegionId = regionId
        }));

        ////This is where a different, more frustrating logical error lives but isn't related to my EF error
        ////Attempting to model after: https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/data/ef-rp/intro/samples/cu/Pages/Instructors/InstructorCoursesPageModel.cshtml.cs

        var selectedRegionHS = new HashSet<string>(SelectedRegions);
        var regionOrders = new HashSet<int>(OrderToUpdate.OrderRegions.Select(c => c.Order.Id)); 
        foreach (var thisregion in _context.Region) 
        {
            if (selectedRegionHS.Contains(thisregion.Id.ToString())) 
            {
               if (!regionOrders.Contains(thisregion.Id)) 
                {
                    OrderToUpdate.OrderRegions.Add( 
                       new OrderRegion
                        {
                            OrderId = OrderToUpdate.Id,
                            RegionId = thisregion.Id
                        });
                }
            }

           else
           {
                if (regionOrders.Contains(thisregion.Id))
                {
                    OrderRegion RegionToRemove = OrderToUpdate.OrderRegions.SingleOrDefault(i => i.RegionId == thisregion.Id);
                    _context.Remove(RegionToRemove);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show what your TryUpdateModelAsync method is doing? Usually this error happens when the context already has an object and you try attaching an item with the same key, causing the duplicate.

Comment: Actually if the error is on an OrderRegion object, might be in the UpdateOrderRegions method where your issue is. Can you show us this method's code?

Comment: Yeah, `TryUpdateModelAsync` is part of the framework. It's the code in `UpdateOrderRegions` that is causing the issue (likely `UpdateOrderStores` too, so you might as well post that too).

Comment: Updated. @chris UpdateOrderStores is exactly the same, just a different entity, agreed, issue will be there too.

Comment: @Derek this selects a list of Order IDs, which you then use to compare against Region IDs, do you need to switch this to c.Region.Id instead?  
       var regionOrders = new HashSet<int>(OrderToUpdate.OrderRegions.Select(c => c.Order.Id));

Comment: @jcruz - will give that a whirl (logical error piece) once I get past my change tracking issue - Full stack trace available via PM if interested/needed.

Comment: if I'm reading the code correctly:looks like you are first deleting the join entity in question and then recreating it with whatever is new about it. Then calling save changes. If that's the case, the context is STILL tracking the deleted entity and trying to begin tracking it's "replacement". If that's the case then we *I and others here trying to help) can propose a different path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue occurs when the context already has an item tracked and you explicitly try attaching a new object with the same key.

Considering the error is on OrderRegion and this type has a composite key of OrderId/RegionId, I think it is likely that you are retrieving the OrderRegion and attaching a new OrderRegion with the same OrderId/RegionId combination. You may need to check if an OrderRegion key already exists or clear the Order's regions and rebuild the list to avoid this collision.

I hope this points you in the right direction. Feel free to provide the code where you handle the OrderRegion updates and I'll try to further assist.

Comment: Specifically, when handling M2M relationships in EF, you need to selectively remove items that are no longer select and then selectively add items that are newly selected, leaving any unchanged relationships alone. If you do something like try to replace the entire collection, you'll freak out EF's change tracking.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, my `_context.SaveChangesAsync()` is failing because `UpdateOrderRegions` and `UpdateOrderStores` is screwing with the existing tracked collections?

Comment: @Derek see my latest comment on the question. You may have an issue with your ID list.

Comment: I think the ID is just part of my logical error I'm also working out. I continue to get the error even if I comment that entire section out.

Comment: Progress - okay, if I comment out UpdateOrderRegions and UpdateOrderStore inside my await, the save works for the base entity. So, I think I need to do a Save, then, somehow save the changes to the related entities and then reload the context. Thinking about how I might could do that.

Comment: I guess I need a better way to go about it than this pattern: https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/data/ef-rp/intro/samples/cu/Pages/Instructors/InstructorCoursesPageModel.cshtml.cs
 as 1. logically it hurts my head and 2. it's updating _context in a way that causes the original tracked changes error. Any thoughts on how to grab changes for the M-M relationships and get them into the save in one step?

Comment: You are duplicating your logic. First you are using StoreRegionsToAdd/StoreRegionsToDelete and iterating through those with their respective operations on the Order object. After that you are using the sample logic from your Github link. You should only need to do one or the other, not both.

Comment: That was it! Stripped it all out and went for a bulk update which was way easier to do anyways. Thank you all for the assistance!